# Finding the local extrema of this trigonometric, multivariate function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization

**QUESTION**

Find all extrema and their places for $$ f(x,y) = \mathtt{sin} x + \mathtt{cos} y + \mathtt{cos} (x-y)$$

for $ 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and  $ 0 \le y \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

**ATTEMPT**

I go ahead and find the first order partial derivatives:

$$f_x = \mathtt{cos} x - \mathtt{sin} (x-y) $$
$$f_y = - \mathtt{sin} y +  \mathtt{sin} (x-y) $$

Equating them to zero to find the critical points, I get the following system of equations - *(now this is where things get tricky for me - not completely sure if I'm making the right conclusions)*

For $f_x = 0$:

$$ - \mathtt{sin} y = - \mathtt{sin} (x-y) ...(1) $$
$$\Rightarrow y = x -y \Rightarrow 2y = x ...(2)$$

Then for $f_y = 0$:

$$ \mathtt{cos} x = \mathtt{sin} (x-y)...(3)$$
then from (2):

$$\mathtt{sin} (x-y) = \mathtt {sin} y = \mathtt {sin} \frac{x}{2}...(4) $$
(2) and (3) give:

$$ \mathtt{cos} x = \mathtt{sin} \frac{x}{2}...(5)$$

Now having looked at the sin and cos graph, I found that the two only intersect at $$ \mathtt {sin} \frac{\pi}{4} = \mathtt {cos} \frac{\pi}{4}$$ in the interval given.

I guess I don't know how to move forward from here...

Do I equate the variables to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and feel things out from there? Cause when I do that I come to some weird-looking three-way equality sign equations that don't seem right.

e.g.

$$ x = \frac{x}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

I understand how to find local extrema etc but I think its the sin/cos thing thats messing with me. Basic trigonometry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found ($x = \pi/4$) values of $x$ where $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$. You need to find values of $x$ such that $\cos(x) = \sin(x/2)$ instead (i.e. the graphs of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x/2)$ intersect: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%28x%29%2C+sin%28x%2F2%29 ).

For instance, if $x = -\pi$, then $\sin(-\pi/2) = -1 = \cos(-\pi)$. There are other solutions as well. Of course, you want the answer between $0$ and $\pi/2$, but I'll leave it to you to find it.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was most helpful!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: It might be mentioned that you needn't resort to a graph.  By designating the angle $ \ \phi = \frac{x}{2} \ , $ we can solve the trigonometric equation  $ \ \cos(2 \phi) = \sin(\phi) \ \Rightarrow \ 1 - 2 \sin^2(\phi) = \sin(\phi) \ , $ which leaves us with a quadratic equation in $ \ \sin \phi \ , $ for which the solutions are $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ and -1  .  This gives us three solutions in the principal circle $ \ 0 \le \phi = \frac{x}{2} < 2\pi \  , $ of which only $ \ \phi = \frac{\pi}{6} \ \Rightarrow \ x = \frac{\pi}{3} \ $ lies in the first quadrant.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Oh thank you! Did it later on and found those same values.